# ArgumentOutOfRangeException for input field rendered for List<object>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So i'm making form which includes list of objects. Because its list i cant make a set number of input fields at start so i figured out that everytime button is clicked i will reload view passing to it current model. So every time `Model.Cargo.Count` is higher and it should render input fields for already existing list items and one more additional for new list item.

At start i have 1 input field `[0]` and it shows up properly so i fill it and press button then when i'm debugging it creates properly `[0]` field for existing object with data that i filled earlier but when it tries to render field for another item `[1]` i got error `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

When List is empty, null, i can have as many inputs i want, but when there is at least one item in list, i cant add more.

How can i add more items to the list?

**Part of view:**

```
@{
                int count = 0;
                if(Model != null)
                {
                    if(Model.Cargo != null)
                    {
                        count = Model.Cargo.Count;
                    }
                }
                count++;
                }
            @for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Cargo[i].Amount" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Cargo[i].Amount" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Cargo[i].Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select asp-for="Cargo[i].CargoTypeId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CargoTypes"></select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Cargo[i].CargoTypeId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            }
```

**View model:**

```
[...]
List<Cargo> Cargo { get; set; }
```

**Cargo model:**

```
[...]
int Amount { get; set; }
int CargoTypeId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that creating a new varible that will be a "copy" of your list when your list has items. Or a new List with a new empty Item when your list does not has values.

This will solve the problem with `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

You'll need to use a new variable because Model of a View is readonly.

```
@{

    bool myListIsEmpty = Model?.Cargo == null || !Model?.Cargo.Any();
    var myList = myListIsEmpty 
        ? new List<Cargo>() { new Cargo() } //Add new empty item on list.
        : Model.Cargo; // "Copy" of your List from your model


        @for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Cargo[i].Amount" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Cargo[i].Amount" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Cargo[i].Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select asp-for="Cargo[i].CargoTypeId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CargoTypes"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Cargo[i].CargoTypeId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        }

}
```

To add more Items in your list you need to wrap the html each result of the for loop into a  tag that will post the new value to your controller. Then render the view again with the new itens.